# Populating text input field in jsf with getParameter value?

Tags: jsf

I need to get parameter that is passed in URL with parameter name "ONum" and input its value in orderNum field.

```
<h:panelGroup>
<h:inputText id="orderNum" value="#{LoginBean.orderNum}" size="18" maxlength="17" tabindex="1" title="Order Number" disabled="#{LoginBean.disableField}"/>
</h:panelGroup>
```

Before doing that, I need to check for #{LoginBean.orderNum} does not return a value then get the parameter contents from ONum and display it in orderNum text input field.
If it returns a value then ignore doing this.
Please help me in doing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An wasy way would be to read the parameter value from the request directly and fill it in the bean.

```
@SessionScoped
public class LoginBean {

    private String orderNum;

    public String getOrderNum() {
        if (getRequestParameter("onum") != null) {
            orderNum = getRequestParameter("onum");
        }
        return orderNum;
    }       

    private String getRequestParameter(String name) {
        return ((HttpServletRequest)FacesContext.currentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest()).getParameter(name);
    } 
    // ...
```

That should be enough.

Comment: Fine.. But I am not getting getParameter() method for getRequest() method. orderNum = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest().???

Comment: Cast it to `HttpServletRequest`.

Comment: thanks its working fine. But when I try to reload the page with different ONum querystring value, its not getting updated. I hope its because my LoginBean scope is Session scoped. Is there a way to overcome this? Like I want updated text field on each reload of the page with whatever query string is there.

Comment: a a, You can read the value in the getter, and guarantee that the request parameter will be preferred over the stored value in the bean. This also doesn't ties your bean to the actual xhtml template of the page.

Comment: BalusC, can you please expand on why I shouldn't do that in the getter, but do it instead in the bean/xhtml combo?

Comment: I am using jsf 1.1 and i think f:event is not there. Is there any other event?

Comment: You don't need any <f:event> inside the xhtml if you update the value in the getter. The code in my response is literally all you need.